# Power series help please!

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$ \frac{2}{3-x}  $$

I need to find a power series representation for this. I figured i'd pull the two out, but I can't figure out what to do with the three.

Comment: $$\frac23\left(1-\frac x3\right)^{-1}$$ and check for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that for $|x|<1$:
$$\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$
So you'd like to bring your function in a similar form. You can do that by manipulating as follows:
$$\frac{2}{3-x} = \frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{1-\frac{x}{3}} = \frac{2}{3}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)^n$$

Answer (score 0):

We know that $1 + r + r^2 + r^3......= \dfrac{1}{1-r}$. So we can write $\dfrac{2}{3-x} = \frac{2}{3}\dfrac{1}{1-\frac{x}{3}} = \frac{2}{3}(1+\frac{x}{3}+\frac{x^2}{9} + \frac{x^3}{27} + \frac{x^4}{81}.......)= \frac{2}{3}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(\frac{x}{3})^n$

Comment: ..and the series represents the function *only* for $\;\left|\frac x3\right|<1\iff |x|<3\ldots$

Answer (score 0):

Consider $${2\over 3-x}={2\over 3}{1\over (1-{x\over 3})}={2\over 3}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left({x\over 3}\right)^n=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty{x^n\over 3^{n+1}}.$$